# TikzEdt does not show lines. Looks as if the line width is 0

Tags: tikz-pgf

I downloaded TikzEdt for  x86_64 GNU/Linux (Ubuntu).

I get the points where I click as an "X" but that is all. I cannot see any lines. Here is the picture: (I updated the picture)

[image]

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Please do not post screen shots but codes. BTW, if your list of coordinates has only one element, you should not be surprised to see only a cross.

Comment: @marmot.  Probably some curves might have one point but some have more than one point. So, that is not the problem. I need to show a screen shot because this does not seem to be a TikZ problem but a problem on the GUI application.

Comment: For those not aware the example given above is from an answer below and should show a Pythagorean triangle between the lower and left points With ABCD at each node, currently the letters and vectors are all appearing at datum 0,0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certainly you should have at least one line since using what I can see of your code it should have produced one "STRAIGHT CURVE" !
Assuming there is a valid terminated co-ordinate and further strings hidden ? much as I have until I have them !

I do understand they were probably random stabs at the work area to illustrate the problem but without a copy of your hidden code it is difficult to check, anyway I got enough to confirm you "should" see at least this line. However as marmot has pointed out most of what we see are simple a point that a Bezier curve **could** pass through if it was constructed in a sequence.

If your hardware is not showing the lines without any "latex path is missing" warning (the most common issue) then since this is very old and not well updated software you might consider the many alternatives.

[image]

Cut and paste this code as produced by the node and edge buttons to see if you get a Pythagorean triangle

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node (v1) at (0,0) {A};
\node (v2) at (0,3) {B};
\node (v3) at (4,3) {C};
\node (v4) at (4,0) {D};

\draw  (v1) edge (v2);
\draw  (v2) edge (v4);
\draw  (v4) edge (v1);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Each user run will have a different temporary file name in the case above

Your tex is built in your temp folder and your file was TE_temp_preview8370.tex it may help if you can post the TeX but I don't think that file itself is the issue
There is another file TE_temp_preview8370_bb.txt that should look like which is holding the bounding box that controls overall scaling -9.92842pt,-9.59508pt,123.80884pt,94.95331pt

It is worth checking the Settings Compiler `Code Prepend`
includes the following preamble

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath, amssymb,bm,color}
\usepackage[margin=0cm,nohead]{geometry}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
% needed for BB
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
```

and Append of course should simply be

```
\end{document}
```

Also the Precompilation Arguments should be similar to (It may vary for  each OS)

```
-ini -jobname="$JOBNAME$" "&pdflatex $FILENAME$\dump"
```

**This preamble** is held in the **compiler settings** and applied to the temporary file **There should be a reset button** or similar option to replace it if not initialised or corrupted.

Comment: I updated the picture. The problem is still there, although there is a tiny object in the lower left vertex. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.

I added the preamble

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
```

[image: line betwen points (0,0) and (0,5)]

Here is the screen capture for a simple test.

Comment: The preamble is held in the compiler settings and applied to the temporary file There should be a reset button to replace if corrupted There may still be a  background access issue if its added twice but if You are happy its resolved accept your own answer

Comment: @KJO :  I tried that many times. Please correct me if I an wrong: There is an option called "Settings", from the many options (General, Editor, Compiler, Parser and Overlay), I picked Compiler. Then I inserted all those preamble instructions there. Still it would not do it. Can it be something else?

Comment: I do not use this app only fire it up to reflect issues others are having the way it works on windows (my OS) is to load temporary files into the user area (that may have readwrite problems) then it calls TeX in the background so if packages need loading on the fly that can be an issue. as it runs mptopdf and some other less common ones the preamble is held in the app to build the temp file and although windows had gone through several beta phases the Linux version had much less history so may still have some odd ways of working. I will paste the full preamble as its possible it may be lacking

Comment: I think sequence:  "Compilation -> (Re-)generate precompiled headers"  was the missing link in my process.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks can you confirm on Linux what the precompilation options are they may differ from those for windows which are -ini -jobname="$JOBNAME$" "&pdflatex $FILENAME$\dump"

Comment: @KJO  -ini -jobname="$JOBNAME$" "&pdflatex $FILENAME$\dump"

Comment: :-) looks like they should work across platform then but I thought the & perhaps should be different as in DOS (windows) it is a command separator, but I thought Linux uses &&